# PHP Lento - Código ou Hospedagem?

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou tendo problemas frequentes com o PHP, talvez porque estou criando de maneira "simples", ou seria minha hospedagem que é básica?

Uso o plano Hospedagem I da Locaweb.

Estou criando um sisteminha que irá fazer dois SELECT no SQL Server, pegando todos os CEP's de dois meses diferentes, para depois compará-los.

Em unidades onde retornam menos resultados o programa funciona corretamente. Mas em unidades que o retorno é bem maior, a página trava com erro 503.

### Index.php

```
<?
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    $cep = preg_replace("/[^0-9\s]/", "", $a['cep']);
    $cepCompara = preg_replace("/[^0-9\s]/", "", $b['cep']);
 return $a['cep'] > $b['cep'];
}

$mes = $_GET['mes'];
$mesAnt = $mes-1;
$unidade = $_GET['unidade'];


    $dbhost   = "HOST HEHE";
    $db       = "BANCO";
    $user     = "USER";
    $password = "PASS";

    mssql_connect($dbhost,$user,$password) or die("Não foi possível a conexão com o servidor!");
    mssql_select_db("$db") or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados!");

    $sql = "SELECT CtrNro, CtrDstNroCep, CtrDat, CtrQtdPeso, CtrValFreteBase
            FROM rlt005
            WHERE CtrUnnCodDestino = $unidade
            AND DATEPART(MONTH, CtrDat) = $mesAnt";

    $consulta = mssql_query($sql);
    $numRegistros = mssql_num_rows($consulta);
    $mesUm = array();
    if ($numRegistros!=0) {
        while ($cadaLinha = mssql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $dados = array(
                "operacional" => $cadaLinha['CtrNro'],
                "cep" => $cadaLinha['CtrDstNroCep'],
                "data" => substr($cadaLinha['CtrDat'],0,3),
                "peso" => $cadaLinha['CtrQtdPeso'],
                "frete" => $cadaLinha['CtrValFreteBase'],
            );
            array_push($mesUm, $dados);
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT CtrNro, CtrDstNroCep, CtrDat, CtrQtdPeso, CtrValFreteBase
            FROM rlt005
            WHERE CtrUnnCodDestino = $unidade
            AND DATEPART(MONTH, CtrDat) = $mes";

    $consulta = mssql_query($sql);
    $numRegistros = mssql_num_rows($consulta);
    $mesDois = array();
    if ($numRegistros!=0) {
        while ($cadaLinha = mssql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $dados = array(
                "operacional" => $cadaLinha['CtrNro'],
                "cep" => $cadaLinha['CtrDstNroCep'],
                "data" => substr($cadaLinha['CtrDat'],0,3),
                "peso" => $cadaLinha['CtrQtdPeso'],
                "frete" => $cadaLinha['CtrValFreteBase'],
            );
            array_push($mesDois, $dados);
        }
    }

    $novo = array();
    $perda = array();
    $totalNovo=0;
    $totalPerda=0;
    
    $tam = sizeof($mesDois);
    for($i=0; $i < $tam; $i++){

        if (!in_array_r($mesDois[$i]['cep'], $mesUm)) {
            if(!in_array_r($mesDois[$i]['cep'], $novo)){
                $totalNovo++;
            }
            array_push($novo, $mesDois[$i]);
        }
    }
    
    $tam = sizeof($mesUm);
    for($i=0; $i < $tam; $i++){
        if (!in_array_r($mesUm[$i]['cep'], $mesDois)) {
            if(!in_array_r($mesUm[$i]['cep'], $perda)){
                $totalPerda++;
            }
            array_push($perda, $mesUm[$i]);
        }
    }

?>
<header>
        <section class="wrap-center clearfix">
            <div class="content-head">
                <h1>Unidade <?php echo $unidade; ?></h1>
                <p>Perdas e Ganhos do mês <?php echo $mes; ?> em relação ao mês <?php echo $mesAnt; ?></p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
        <div class="container">
            <section class="card">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $totalPerda; ?></h3>
                
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th style="padding: 2px 4px 2px 17px !important;">●</th>
                            <th>Operacional</th>
                            <th>CEP</th>
                            <th>Peso (Kg)</th>
                            <th>Frete (R$)</th>
                            
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                         <?php
                         $tam = sizeof($perda);
                            for($i=0; $i < $tam; $i++){
                                echo '<tr>
                                <td style="padding:2px 0px 2px 17px !important;"><a href="#" onclick="popUP('.preg_replace("/^(\d{5})(\d{3})$/", "\\1-\\2", $novo[$i]['cep']).')"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                                        <td>'.$perda[$i]['operacional'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.preg_replace("/^(\d{5})(\d{3})$/", "\\1-\\2", $perda[$i]['cep']).'</td>
                                        <td>'.$perda[$i]['peso'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.str_replace(".", ",", $perda[$i]['frete']).'</td>
                                        
                                    </tr>';
                            }
                         ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
                
            </section>
            <section class="card">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $totalNovo; ?></h3>
                
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th style="padding: 2px 4px 2px 17px !important;">●</th>
                            <th>Operacional</th>
                            <th>CEP</th>
                            <th>Peso (Kg)</th>
                            <th>Frete (R$)</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                         <?php
                            $tam = sizeof($novo);
                            for($i=0; $i < $tam; $i++){
                                echo '<tr>
                                
                                    <td style="padding:2px 0px 2px 17px !important;"><a href="#" onclick="popUP('.preg_replace("/^(\d{5})(\d{3})$/", "\\1-\\2", $novo[$i]['cep']).')"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                            
                                <td>'.$novo[$i]['operacional'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.preg_replace("/^(\d{5})(\d{3})$/", "\\1-\\2", $novo[$i]['cep']).'</td>
                                        <td>'.$novo[$i]['peso'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.str_replace(".", ",", $novo[$i]['frete']).'</td>
                                        
                                    </tr>';
                            }
                         ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
                
            </section>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sendo sincero, teu código esta com várias "recursões", é bem provável que seja ele o problema mesmo. Mas não consegui entender bem o objetivo para tentar simplificar

Comment: `Mas em unidades que o retorno é bem maior,`.. Maior quanto? Mil registros? 10 mil registros? O normal é criar uma paginação para evitar um volume muito grande de dados numa única página.

Comment: @DanielOmine Em unidades menores o retorno é de cerca de 2mil registros, e em maiores cerca de 20mil...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o objetivo é pegar todos os CEP's do mes 6 e todos do mes 5 (por exemplo), e comparar para saber se perdemos algum.

Comment: Crie uma paginação. Nunca retorne uma quantidade tão grande. Mesmo o menor que é 2 mil já é muito. Paginação é 50 por página, 100 por página. Até bem menos que isso, por exemplo, 20, 30

Comment: @PedroDaher: Evite construções do tipo "AND DATEPART(MONTH, CtrDat) = $mesAnt", pois elas são non-SARGable.  Melhor utilizar algo como "AND CtrDat between $inicioMesAnt and $finalMesAnt" // 
Vide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão é confusa mas se você está tentando pegar ceps de dois meses distintos para comparar qual cep perdeu no mês atual. Você deveria montar uma querie com apenas um select pegando todos os registros do mês 05 e utilizando o comando **NOT IN** para filtrar todos os registros não contindos no mês 06. A lógica seria

> "**RECUPERE TODOS OS REGISTROS DO MES 05 QUE NÃO ESTÃO CONTIDOS NO MÊS 06**"

Exemplo simplório de uso:

```
Select * from funcionario where CODFUNC not in (select CODFUNC from FILIAIS)
```

Você poderia montar isso :

```
SELECT CtrNro, CtrDstNroCep, CtrDat, CtrQtdPeso, CtrValFreteBase
        FROM rlt005
        WHERE CtrUnnCodDestino = $unidade 
        AND DATEPART(MONTH, CtrDat) = '05'
        AND CtrDstNroCep not in 
        (SELECT CtrDstNroCep FROM rlt005 WHERE CtrUnnCodDestino = $unidade 
        AND DATEPART(MONTH, CtrDat) = '06');
```

Acredito que a querie esteja correta, não tenho total entendimento de sua estrutura de tabela. Mas essa é a forma correta de fazer, poupando o máximo de recursos ao invés de utilizar um quilo de loops com php que ocupa muita memória e CPU. Atente-se que o campo **CtrDat** , **CtrDstNroCep**  devem também ser um indíce em sua tabela para agilizar as consultas.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou certinho e ficou bem rápido até.

Comment: Foi de um enorme prazer ! Abraços.

Comment: Só acrescentando, quando se faz consultas constantes na base de dados uma dica considerável é indexar as colunas que são utilizadas para tais fins. Isso agiliza ainda mais a busca.